# Data Calculated From File Size Using Batch Script is in Negative for some and positive for some

Tags: batch-file, command-line, cmd, batch-processing, fat32

I have a batch Script for Data Calculation but the data is unusual. even though the limit is 32 bits but even for less its coming in negative. please help.

The following is the script

```
forfiles /p "V:\DVRelease\SLR\ScanTransfer\Export\Archive" /s /d -90 /c "cmd /c echo @fsize & del /Q @file">>V:\DVRelease\CalculationFile.txt

forfiles /p "V:\DVRelease\SLR\ScanTransfer\Import\Log" /s /d -90 /c "cmd /c echo @fsize & del /Q @file">>V:\DVRelease\CalculationFile.txt

forfiles /p "V:\DVRelease\SLR\ScanTransfer\Import\Archive" /s /d -90 /c "cmd /c echo @fsize & del /Q @file">>V:\DVRelease\CalculationFile.txt

forfiles /p "V:\DVRelease\SLR\ScanTransfer\Import\Temp" /s /d -90 /c "cmd /c echo @fsize & del /Q @file">>V:\DVRelease\CalculationFile.txt

forfiles /p "V:\DVRelease\SLR\ScanTransfer\Import\New folder" /s /d -90 /c "cmd /c echo @fsize & del /Q @file">>V:\DVRelease\CalculationFile.txt

forfiles /p "V:\DVRelease\SLR\ScanTransfer\Import\Investigating" /s /d -90 /c "cmd /c echo @fsize & del /Q @file">>V:\DVRelease\CalculationFile.txt

forfiles /p "V:\DVRelease\SLR\SLR" /s /d -90 /c "cmd /c echo @fsize & del /Q @file">>V:\DVRelease\CalculationFile.txt

forfiles /p "V:\DVRelease\SLR\Trigger\Scanning\logs" /s /d -90 /c "cmd /c echo @fsize & del /Q @file">>V:\DVRelease\CalculationFile.txt

forfiles /p "V:\DVRelease\SLR\Working\logs\Category" /s /d -90 /c "cmd /c echo @fsize & del /Q @file">>V:\DVRelease\CalculationFile.txt

forfiles /p "V:\DVRelease\SLR\Working\logs\Dirmon" /s /d -90 /c "cmd /c echo @fsize & del /Q @file">>V:\DVRelease\CalculationFile.txt

forfiles /p "V:\DVRelease\SLR\Working\logs\PermDocs" /s /d -90 /c "cmd /c echo @fsize & del /Q @file">>V:\DVRelease\CalculationFile.txt

forfiles /p "V:\DVRelease\SLR\Working\logs\Transfer" /s /d -90 /c "cmd /c echo @fsize & del /Q @file">>V:\DVRelease\CalculationFile.txt

forfiles /p "V:\DVRelease\SLR\Working\logs\XMLImport" /s /d -90 /c "cmd /c echo @fsize & del /Q @file">>V:\DVRelease\CalculationFile.txt

forfiles /p "V:\CMI\SLR\CASENOTESLOG" /s /d -90 /c "cmd /c echo @fsize & del /Q @file">>V:\DVRelease\CalculationFile.txt

forfiles /p "V:\CMI\SLR\IN\ARCHIVE" /s /d -90 /c "cmd /c echo @fsize & del /Q @file">>V:\DVRelease\CalculationFile.txt

forfiles /p "V:\CMI\SLR\LOG" /s /d -90 /c "cmd /c echo @fsize & del /Q @file">>V:\DVRelease\CalculationFile.txt

forfiles /p "V:\CMI\SLR\OUT\BUFFER" /s /d -90 /c "cmd /c echo @fsize & del /Q @file">>V:\DVRelease\CalculationFile.txt

forfiles /p "V:\CMI\TrackDocument" /s /d -90 /c "cmd /c echo @fsize & del /Q @file">>V:\DVRelease\CalculationFile.txt

set sz=0

for /F %%a IN (V:\DVRelease\CalculationFile.txt) do set /a "sz=sz+%%a"

echo %date% size Deleted: %sz% Bytes>> V:\DVRelease\DataPurgingLog.txt

echo 0 > V:\DVRelease\CalculationFile.txt
```

---

```
16/06/2017 size: 95688908 Bytes 17/06/2017 size: 190699856 Bytes
18/06/2017 size: 288026688 Bytes 19/06/2017 size: 738941927 Bytes
20/06/2017 size: 1318320513 Bytes 21/06/2017 size: 2027242389 Bytes
22/06/2017 size: -1658242847 Bytes 23/06/2017 size: -1081463106 Bytes
24/06/2017 size: -1081679150 Bytes 25/06/2017 size: -1076557226 Bytes
26/06/2017 size: -234336671 Bytes 27/06/2017 size: 472276127 Bytes
28/06/2017 size: 1397077743 Bytes 29/06/2017 size: 2136536561 Bytes
30/06/2017 size: -1182863157 Bytes 01/07/2017 size: -1183067763 Bytes
02/07/2017 size: -1180564003 Bytes 03/07/2017 size: -337979418 Bytes
04/07/2017 size: 696381662 Bytes 05/07/2017 size: 1161459262 Bytes
06/07/2017 size: 1846180236 Bytes 07/07/2017 size: -1876917405 Bytes
08/07/2017 size: -1877018504 Bytes 09/07/2017 size: -1873607886 Bytes
10/07/2017 size: -1127889677 Bytes 11/07/2017 size: -561964370 Bytes

12/07/2017 size: 15054159 Bytes
13/07/2017 size: 552787929 Bytes
14/07/2017 size: 552787929 Bytes
15/07/2017 size: 552787929 Bytes
16/07/2017 size: 552788030 Bytes
17/07/2017 size: 556373062 Bytes
```

Comment: It appears that the script is not what produced the output. Please edit the question to include the actual script and actual output.

Comment: You know that the range for 32-bit integers is -2^31 to 2^31-1 since they are signed?

Comment: To show the maximum 32-bits positive number use `set /A 0x7FFFFFFF`; the result is `2147483647`.

Comment: Numbers are limited to 32-bits of precision (signed integers from  `-2147483648` to `2147483647`). Hence,  `set /A 2147483647 + 1` shows `-2147483648` and `set /A 2147483647 + 2147483647` shows `-2` (cf. @Aacini's comment).